# How fast is the perimeter of a square increasing when the area is 25 cm² and the area is increasing at 30 cm²/s?

Tags: calculus

I can't find the answer. Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is area then $\frac{dA}{dt}$ is rate of change of area with respect to time.

In question given that $\frac{dA}{dt}=30\;cm^2/s$

Now area $A$ and perimeter $P$ are related in square.

If $s$ is one side of square then area of square is $A=s^2$
If $s$ is one side of square then perimeter of square is $P=4s \Rightarrow s=\frac{P}{4}$
putting the value of $s$ into area equation $A=\frac{P^2}{16}$ 
let's call this area perimeter relation equation.

Differentiating both sides with respect to $t$

$\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{2P}{16}\frac{dP}{dt}$

At $t=0$, Area $A=25\;cm^2\Rightarrow s=5\;cm\Rightarrow P=20\;cm$

Put the  value  of $P$ and $\frac{dA}{dt}$ into differential form of area perimeter equation.

$\frac{dP}{dt}=12\;cm/s$

Comment: Sorry for my calculation mistake

Comment: The answer is right or not?

Comment: It's right answer. you can check it by putting value into differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $A = a^2 \implies \dfrac{dA}{dt} = 2a\dfrac{da}{dt}$, and $P = 4a \implies \dfrac{dP}{dt} = 4\dfrac{da}{dt}$

Comment: Hint: when the side increases by a factor $\lambda$, the perimeter increases by $\lambda$ and the area by $\lambda^2$.